# resolveUri failed on bad bitmap in ListView from JSON

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

My problem is to show an imagen into a listview readed from JSON, I read a lot of posts about the issue but no one solved it completely. I cathc the url with `String imagen = e.getString("img_preview_1");` then added it into

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("imagen", imagen);
```

This is my adapter with a String and the image

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.activity_videos_categoria, 
                        new String[] { "title", "imagen" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.from , R.id.imageView1});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I tried chenging the type in the Map asn Object but still same problem

The error in LogCat is resolveUri failed on bad bitmap

Thank you

Comment: Whats your Uri  like?

Comment: uri: http://xxx/yyyy/zzzz.png Is that what you mean?

Comment: what is the value of `img_preview_1` ?

Comment: @PareshMayani the value in JSON is "img_preview_1":"http:\\www.yyy.zzzz.png"

Comment: Where have you used `map`?

Comment: mylist.add(map); for the listAdapter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is you are setting a `url`(Which is of String type) directly to the `imageview` and requesting the `SimpleAdapter` to bind it to the `imageview`. I would suggest you to use other adapters as in my below code. Because `SimpleAdapter` and `SimpleCursorAdapter` are mostly used when you have data in the `local(sqlite) database` to make the content reflected directly on the `listview`. But here you get the data from the server. So here you go with it.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
           vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null); //This should be your row layout

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageview1); //image

        HashMap<String, String> localhash = new HashMap<String, String>();
        localhash = data.get(position);

        String currenttitle = localhash.get("title");
        String imagepath = localhash.get("imagen");

        titleTextView.setText(currenttitle);

        if(!imagepath.equals(""))
        {
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imagepath , thumb_image);

        }
        return vi;
    }

}
```

You set the above adapter to your `listview` in the below way. Include the below code after you load the data from the network. To load the data from the server, make sure you don't run the network operations on UI thread. For this you can make use of AsyncTask,Handlers, Service etc., If you use AsyncTask, include the below lines in `onPostExecute()`.

```
CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(YourActivity.this, dataArrayList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this helps and btw sorry for the delay in answering.

Comment: You are right Appu I followed this post http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-json-parsing-with-jsonobject-and-loading-to-listview-example/ and saw that I needed a custom adapter. Thanks a lot Appu