# Json image cant load

Tags: android, json

i am getting "text" form json, but i can't get "images".

public class JsonSampleActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private Context context;

// url to make request
private static String url = "http://www.bounty4u.com/android/sample_json.txt";

    //JSON Node names
 private static final String TAG_TITLE = "name";
 private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "url";

    // contacts JSONArray
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

ListView lv ;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new ProgressTask(JsonSampleActivity.this).execute();

    }



private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ListActivity activity;

        public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        context = activity;

    }

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

    /** application context. */
    private Context context;

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_IMAGE },
                new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.image1 });

        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

        JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

            try {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
               String vfuel = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
               String vimage = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                map.put(TAG_TITLE, vfuel);
                map.put(TAG_IMAGE,vimage);

                jsonlist.add(map);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

I am getting an error : resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://www.bounty4u.com/android/images/angie.jpg

so tell me what is problem?

Comment: Please add your LogCat

Comment: could you show the code where you assign the image to the ImageView?

Comment: <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

Comment: LogCat:  resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://www.bounty4u.com/android/images/angie.jpg resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://www.bounty4u.com/android/images/ashton.jpg resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://www.bounty4u.com/android/images/hugh.jpg Like this.......?

Comment: Have you seen this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059110/resolveuri-failed-on-bad-bitmap-in-listview-from-json

Comment: 09-02 22:36:59.009: I/System.out(476): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://www.bounty4u.com/android/images/angie.jpg